# LegacyAddin works no more in NATVIS Visual Studio 2022

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, visual-studio-2022, visualizer

LegacyAddin worked fine until VisualStudio 2019. But the 'natvis' code below stopped to work since Visual Studio 2022:

```
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">
    <Type Name="ATL::COleDateTime">
        <DisplayString LegacyAddin="ClassLibrary1.dll" Export='Class1'></DisplayString>
    </Type>
</AutoVisualizer>
```

When I compile ClassLibrary1.dll in C++ (as used to be) it not even loads. When I compile it using C#, it loads but I get the following message:

Natvis: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\CardiosAddin.natvis(4,3): Error: Failed to load addin from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\ClassLibrary1.dll for type ATL::COleDateTime: Addin dll missing export 汃獡ㅳ.

Note: the japanese characters seems to be the `Export` string interpreted as unicode...

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Just compile the dll (ATL C++ is OK; C# not tested) in 64 bits (x64 Platform) and export the dll functions using `extern "C"`.